# docker deosnt install package.json packages

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

I'm trying to run my nodeJS application on a docker.

The docker should contain `Node.js` and an `SQL` service.

`docker-compose.yaml`:

```yaml
version: '3.9'
services:
    microsoft_sql_db_container:
        image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
        container_name: microsoft_sql_db_container
        environment:
            - MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=Abcd1234!
            - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
            - MSSQL_AGENT_ENABLED=true
        ports:
            - 1433:1433
        networks:
            - dashboard_network
        volumes:
            - microsoft_sql_db_data_container:/var/opt/mssql
    backend:
        container_name: backend
        build:
            context: ../
            dockerfile: ./UserManagementApi/docker/Dockerfile
        ports:
            - 3000:3000
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - microsoft_sql_db_container
        networks:
            - dashboard_network
        volumes:
            - type: bind
              source: ./UserManagementApi/src
              target: /app/user-management/src
            - /app/user-management/node_modules
volumes:
    microsoft_sql_db_data_container:
networks:
    dashboard_network:
        driver: bridge
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:16.14.0

RUN npm i -g pnpm@7.29.1

WORKDIR /app

RUN mkdir userManagement

WORKDIR ./userManagement

COPY ./UserManagementApi/package.json ./

RUN pnpm i

COPY ./UserManagementApi/ .

CMD ["pnpm", "start:dev"]
```

When I'm navigation to the app/node_modules/ inside the docker image, I see all the packages.

Although, when I'm catting some random package - the package seems to be empty.

Thus, I'm receiving the following error when I'm running the image:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/app/userManagement/node_modules/@nestjs/cli/bin/nest.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []
}
ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.
```

My question is, the copy of the nude_module seems to work fine, but the `NPM i` seems to not work as expected.

Thanks in Advance for any help!

Comment: It looks like your `node_modules` tree is coming from an anonymous volume and the content of the image is completely ignored.  Does it help to delete the Compose `volumes:` block that hides the image content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may have to switch your workdir to UserManagementApi before running command "pnpm i" so that package.json is visible